# What the difference between .click and .change on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, click

I was looking around to add an event to a checkbox and I would have thought people would use `.change` to set up a change event but instead I found that people are using `.click`

Is there a reason for this? They both seem to work fine both with clicked events and with keyboard changes. Am I missing something?

If you don't believe me then **[try it out yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/wB3YQ/)**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`onchange` in IE only fires when the checkbox loses focus.  So if you tab to it, hit space a few times, tab out, you'll only get one `onchange` event, but several `onclick` events.

Note: this is one of the very, very, very rare times when IE's behavior is correct (according to spec) and other browsers are wrong.

Comment: also interesting didn't know you click things like that

Comment: actually it works for clicks too.  If you click the checkbox twice and then click somewhere else you won't get an `onchange` event (clicking it twice returns it to its initial value), but you'll get two `onclick` events.

Comment: Worth noting that onchange only fires when the focus changes in text fields - i wasn't aware that the behavior was different for checkboxes, but i suppose it's because their focus is not as well defined.

Answer (score 10):

Two reasons why `onclick` is preferred over `onchange`.

1. Internet Explorer only fires the onchange event when the checkbox loses the focus (onblur). So `onclick` is more of a cross browser solution.
2. `onchange` happens only after the element lose focus.(You wont see a difference since you are calling alert and losing focus on every change). The pseudo code on MDC pretty much explains the [`element.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange) implementation.

   ```
   control.onfocus = focus;
   control.onblur = blur;

   function focus () {
       original_value = control.value;
   }

   function blur () {
       if (control.value != original_value)
           control.onchange();
   }
   ```

Comment: FYI, all browsers other than IE (well FF, Chrome, Safari anyway) fire onchange immediately on checkboxes.

Comment: @cwolves: i know that. but 56% of users still use IE :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: Your link says 45% average :)

Comment: was mentioning the net applications share :)

Comment: :) anyway its much lesser than i originally anticipated. from a programmers perspective this is very good :)

Comment: Posting from the far future, where only 1.98% - 3.90% of all users use IE.

Answer (score 0):

.change doesn't work correctly for at least some popular browsers in relation to key changes (the user selecting option with up/down arrow keys) but then .click doesn't overcome this either. Sometimes the use of keyup or keydown or something is used in conjunction with .change to overcome this issue however it starts to get a bit messy when you user's tab the document as this can trigger the key event if it's not explicitly handled within the callback. All in all it's a shame that .change doesn't work as you would expect as it would solve some time consuming issues.

Answer (score 0):

yes both work, only click does not look at the actual object changing (like a checkbox that gets checked), change does.

Technically it is more reliable but in practise both work.

Answer (score 0):

They may both fire a change in the value by default, but you may override the onClick logic to NOT change the value of a chackbox. You may change the value via another entry point. So having a .click and a .change is needed.

edit - I also agree with Dr Rob