# jQuery remove class on uncheck of checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the jQuery function below that adds some classes to elements when a checkbox is checked which is all good.
But if the checkbox is then unchecked, I want to then remove these same classes from the elements.
I'm guessing it would be with .removeClass but I can't figure out where to add it.
Thanks

```
function countDouble() {      
    var d = $("input.double:checked").length;
    var s = $("input.single:checked").length;

    if (d === 2) {
   $(".twoday input:disabled").addClass("disabled");
       $(".twoday input:disabled + label").addClass("disabled");
    };
    if (s === 1) {
   $(".oneday input:disabled").addClass("disabled");
       $(".oneday input:disabled + label").addClass("disabled");
    };
};

jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
    countDouble();
    $(":checkbox").click(countDouble);  
});
```

Comment: Can you have the html posted?

Answer (score 0):

"disabled" is not so much a class as it is an attribute.

Explained here: [jQuery - checkbox enable/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330209/jquery-checkbox-enable-disable)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am adding the class 'disabled' to the disabled checkboxes. They all become disabled when one is checked. But what I am stuck on is then removing that class if the checkbox is unchecked (and they all become enabled again)

Answer (score 0):

See the below code:

```
$('#myform :checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        // the checkbox was checked, call the function to addClass 
    } else {
        // the checkbox was unchecked, call the function to removeClass
    }
});
```

**Update:** Clarifying on `.click` vs `.change`, here's an answer that explains it:

> The checkbox just happens to be the special case where change and
>   click are interchangable, because you can't fire the change event
>   without also triggering click.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox)

Comment: You should use "change" instead of "click" because i can update the input using the keyboard.

Comment: Click event also works with keyboard input. See this fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/4E7hB/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on your code that will work. You can add extra calls within the conditional statement to suit your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/UefHa/

```
 function countDouble() {      
    var d = $("input.double").is(':checked');
    var s = $("input.single").is(':checked');

    if (d === true) {
       $(".twoday input").prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
    } else {
       $(".twoday input").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
    }

    if (s === true) {
       $(".oneday input").prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
    } else {
       $(".oneday input").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change( function() {
        countDouble();
    });
});
```