# Run JavaScript function on check change of checkbox inside a div with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've a check box inside a repeater control. the repeater may have variable number of items.
I need to call a js function whenever a checkbox with id "**DFO_MFO**" of any list item is checked/unchecked. how can I do that?
I've tried the following code but it is not working.

```
$(".DFO_MFO").change(function () {
    DfoMfoChecked($(this));
})
```

**ASP.Net Markup**

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="DFO_MFO" class="DFO_MFO"></asp:CheckBox>
```

**HTML Rendering**

```
<span class="DFO_MFO">
    <input id="ctl00_PageContent_BULK_WOTableControlRepeater_ctl00_DFO_MFO" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PageContent$BULK_WOTableControlRepeater$ctl00$DFO_MFO">
</span>
```

Comment: if the `DFO_MFO` is the id of a control. 1). you cannot have multiple elements with same id 2). You have to use `#` for id selector and `.` for class selector

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal You need to read the question. The checkbox is an ASP.NET control, which is in a repeater. That means the `id`s generated are unique, like the **HTML Rendering** part shows. Also, why are you een bringing up the difference between `#` and `.` in selectors? The OP is targeting the `class` correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".DFO_MFO").children('input').change(function () {
    DfoMfoChecked($(this));
})
```

Comment: Thanks.. That did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal :: I was trying to.. but it was saying "You can accept the answer after 5 mins.." :(

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a change event to a `span` element. But a `span` element **does not** have a `change` event associated to it.

In this case the `change` event will work because of event bubbling.

Use the `context` selector or `.find` to target the inputs and then assign the change event to the checkbox.

```
$("input", ".DFO_MFO").change(function () {
      DfoMfoChecked($(this));
})
```

Also it is better to attach events using `.on()` if you are `using jQuery 1.7 and above`

```
 $("input", ".DFO_MFO").on('change', function () {
          DfoMfoChecked($(this));
    })
```

Comment: That's incredibly wrong. Ever heard of event bubbling? http://jsfiddle.net/m6Uta/ . I'm not saying it should be done that way, but you shouldn't mislead the OP

Comment: It's also not "better" to attach events with `.on()`. Using `.change()` is just a shortcut, does the same thing, and it works in older versions of jQuery, while `.on()` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Use `.click()` and inside the event handler function check if the element `.is(':checked')` and switch on that. Or in your case just call `DfoMfoChecked($(this))`;

Comment: `click` alone isn't enough. You can toggle a checkbox by navigating to it with `[tab]` and pressing `[space]`. Also, if you have a label attached to it, you can toggle it by clicking the label, this also doesn't generate a click on the checkbox element.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen And it works just the same. You should test it before you declare something like that. http://jsfiddle.net/ZssTb/1/

Comment: That must be some jQuery magic then .. I'm stumped. I don't know if I approve of this.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox) and [this W3C document](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35)