# Toggle checked on checkbox when spacebar is pressed

Tags: jquery

I have a small snippet of code which I use to toggle the `checked` property of a checkbox when the <kbd>space bar</kbd> is pressed.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#example').prop('checked', function() {
      return !this.checked;
    });
  }
});
```

The above works fine in Chrome v30 and IE10, but not in Firefox v24. The problem occurs when you **click** the checkbox, and then use the space bar to toggle it, it momentarily checks it, and then unchecks it, and vice versa.

I believe the problem has something to do with the fact that the `click` event is triggered in Firefox when using `keydown()`, despite using `e.preventDefault()` (which prevents the click event from triggering in both Chrome and IE).

I tried using the same code, binding the `keyup` event. This fixed the problem in Firefox, but then introduced the same problem to IE.

#### [Here's the fiddle where Firefox is affected](http://jsfiddle.net/3pmvw/8/)

Does anybody know why this is happening, and how I can get around it?

Comment: ah, now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's normal behaviour. You are hitting two different events (the checkbox change, and the keydown on document), so we cannot expect `.preventDefault()` to work.

I'd simply add a condition for that:

```
if (e.target != $('#example').get(0)) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        $('#example').prop('checked', ! $('#example').is(":checked"));
    }
}
```

We check that the "space" event is not triggered by the checkbox itself.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3pmvw/23/

Comment: One more thing, like @davidkonrad example, you don't need that function closure for the property. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/3pmvw/50/ (if you are ok, I'll update the solution above to make it more correct).

Comment: i did it that way so that I didn't have to call `#example` from the dom a second time, not that it would make much difference

Comment: I still don't fully understand why `preventDefault()` doesn't prevent the click event from firing in Firefox when the element has focus. Maybe it has something to do with the order in which events are dispatched, as `keyup()` does prevent it in Firefox, but not IE

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the thing is that for checkboxes the browser fires an event internally (click), which is different and not in the same event chain as your `keydown`. No idea about ordering in different browsers :?. See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
        event = e || window.event;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            if (jQuery("#indian_holder").is(":checked")) {
                jQuery("#indian_holder").prop("checked", false);
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#indian_holder").prop("checked", true);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is perfectly work for me.