# Chekbox click event not getting triggered on checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox with id myopt and I have a click event handler as below;

```
$("#globalBody").on("click", "#myopt", function (event) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Now in my code, I do

```
$("#myopt").attr("checked",true);
```

My question is this does not trigger the click event handler above. It gets called if I click the checkbox manually.

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to programmatically invoke the click handler

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

*Script*

```
$("#myopt").prop("checked",true).trigger('click');
```

Note: I would recommend you to use `change` event

```
$("#globalBody").on("change", "#myopt", function (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});

//Change
$("#myopt").prop("checked",true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Any reason of using change instead of click ?

Comment: @testndtv, Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox

Comment: Oh yes...and the code above actually unchecks the checkbox !

Comment: @testndtv, Thats what you intented?

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle please https://jsfiddle.net/kwp7sjwf/2/

I have two versions depending on what you need. As I understand it, what you want is to click somewhere inside the `#globalBody` and check the state of `myopt` checkbox. In the above fiddle I did that, but I've placed in comments a code block that handles the 2nd version which is the case where you want to listen only when `myopt` checkbox state changes (clicks directly on the checkbox).
Hope it helps