# jQuery selectable() not responding to checkbox ticks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I've got a set of checkboxes which can all be checked/unchecked easily by dragging the mouse over the labels using selectable() plugin.  But if I specifically click a checkbox input box instead of its label, nothing happens.  I've tried all kinds of combinations using the filter, but nothing seems to work other than using 'label'. I want the behaviour to be the same whether the user drags over the input boxes or the labels. Several hours on this now, please help! Fiddle below.

```
<form>
 <div class='myBoxes'>

  <label>Check 1<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" /> </label>
  <label>Check 2<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" /> </label>
  <label>Check 3<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" /> </label>
  <label>Check 4<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" /> </label>

 </div>
</form>



$(".myBoxes").selectable({

  filter: 'label',

  stop: function() {
    $(".ui-selected input", this).each(function() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).parent().addClass("LabelHighlight")
      } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("LabelHighlight")
      }

    });
  }
});



 label {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label.ui-selecting {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.LabelHighlight {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7xk032m/

Comment: so you need a solution using this plugin?? or any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox is another DOM over the div, so you must attach the same event to it like below:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).parent().addClass("LabelHighlight")
  } else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("LabelHighlight")
  }
});
```

DemoL http://jsfiddle.net/86njvLrw/

Comment: I see, and thank you for your explanation. It does make the code long-winded but I understand that there's little alternative if I want to use this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

*For Me* I wouldn't use the `selectable()` I'll just use `click()` event .. Here is how

```js
$('.myBoxes label').on('click' , function(e){
    $("input:checkbox" , this).change();
});
$("input:checkbox").on("click" , function(e){
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("LabelHighlight");
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label.ui-selecting {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.LabelHighlight {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class='myBoxes'>

    <label>Check 1<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" /> </label>
    <label>Check 2<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" /> </label>
    <label>Check 3<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" /> </label>
    <label>Check 4<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" /> </label>

  </div>
</form>
```

For reference you can take a look at [jQuery difference between change and click event of checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox)

Comment: Yes, this is what I had before the plugin.  However, the dragging and lasso that's made possible by the plugin is excellent for my particular needs here, so I'd rather stick with it if at all possible.

Comment: Its OK @Silverburch if you'll use the plugin for another things .. I posted my answer 1st: I assume that you just need the plugin to do this thing  .. 2nd: to let you know another way of how to do this without plugin .. anyways Have a great day :-)