# Yii2 Jquery onclick not working when check and uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I have to check and uncheck the checkbox along with it, I need to have another action should be done like when I check the textbox should come, and when uncheck that textbox should be gone. For this I have code, but for first time it is working and without reloading the page again Im opening that and checking the checkbox at that time it is not working:

```
$('#feescheduledetail-beyond_drive_time').click(function() {
    if(this.checked){
        $('.field-feescheduledetail-drive_time').show();
    }else{
        $('.field-feescheduledetail-drive_time').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery checkbox checked state changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event)

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` instead of `click`. After page load (inside `document.ready`) You can hide your `textbox` .

```
$(".field-feescheduledetail-drive_time").hide();
$(".feescheduledetail-beyond_drive_time").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.field-feescheduledetail-drive_time').show();
  } else {
    $('.field-feescheduledetail-drive_time').hide();
  }
});
```

Example:

```js
$(".field-feescheduledetail-drive_time").hide();
$(".feescheduledetail-beyond_drive_time").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.field-feescheduledetail-drive_time').show();
  } else {
    $('.field-feescheduledetail-drive_time').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="feescheduledetail-beyond_drive_time" />
<input type="text" class="field-feescheduledetail-drive_time" />
```

For details about`change` vs `click`  see this old [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox) question.