# Check only non-disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sequence of checkboxes that can be disabled or not through the disabled in the input tag

By clicking on the parent checkbox, I need only those NOT disabled to be checked

Current and desired:

[image]
[image]

Code so far:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
   $("input:checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: `$("input:checkbox:not([disabled])")`

Comment: Thank you friends, all the mentioned methods worked perfectly in solving my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector combined with the [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) :

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
   $("input:checkbox:not([disabled])").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

As suggested by [@connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo), you should use `.change()` instead of `.click()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251498/16688813) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS, always preferred:

```js
document.getElementById('checkAll').addEventListener('change', function() {
  for (const cb of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled])')) {
    if (cb !== this) cb.checked = this.checked;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" />
```