# Make div appear (or disappear) on checkbox status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkdisplay').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('.todisplay').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('.todisplay').fadeOut('slow');

    });
});
```

This works great only if I check the .checkdisplay radio button: the div appears, but after, if i uncheck .checkdisplay radio button, the div .todisplay doesn't disappear.

Where i'm wrong? :(

EDIT:

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mse2L/

Comment: can you please add the full code in jsfiddle.?

Comment: Did you included any version of `jquery`?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/JYEHm/) works just fine.  What is your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radio').change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checkdisplay') && this.checked) $('.todisplay').fadeIn('slow');
        else $('.todisplay').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

### **[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Mse2L/4/)**

The problem is, you can't **uncheck** a radiobutton.

Comment: @MattiaDelFranco what about disappear the box when unchecked?

Comment: This will add the event to all input fields on the page and not test the actual button checked but rely on the side effect that the one with the class is checked. Not very elegant. If he changes a type=text and the radio is checked, jQuery will try to fade it in again

Comment: @mplungjan Please look at the update to my answer, now it checks the type

Comment: There is no longer any reason to check the type now you bind to the class of .radio.

Comment: @mplungjan ...okay, removed, so it's basically the first version of my answer... (and my first answer I provided the wrong JSFiddle)

Comment: @SumanBogati ...it does disappear when unchecked, my first answer provided the wrong JSFiddle

Comment: The first version had $("input")

Comment: @MattiaDelFranco see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575338/what-the-difference-between-click-and-change-on-a-checkbox to find out whether to use click or change event.

Comment: Which is why I use onclick in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to test all the radios and only show on the one with the correct class

You could have used ID too

Notice I use `.on("click"` since change needs a blur in some browsers

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/48hzC/)

```
$(function(){
  $("input[name='roomdoor']").on("click",function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("checkdisplay") && this.checked)
        $('.todisplay').fadeIn('slow');
    else
        $('.todisplay').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tested your live demo: when i uncheck the radio button, the div doesn't disappear.

Comment: It certainly does now :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `radio` button, you should use `checkbox` like,

Once a `radio button` having class `checkdisplay` is `checked` then it will be `checked`, how it can be `unchecked`

```
<input type='checkbox' class='checkdisplay' />
<div class='todisplay'>test</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zbcyA/)

**Updated,** try this like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.radio').change(function(){// add onchange on radio class
        // check the radio has checkdisplay class or not
        if($(this).hasClass('checkdisplay') && this.checked)
            $('.todisplay').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('.todisplay').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mse2L/4/)

Comment: I cant use checkbox type, i need radio button.

Comment: @MattiaDelFranco see my updated answer and working demo

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.checkdisplay').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".todisplay").fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(".todisplay").fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Some explanation may help!

Comment: Also does not allow fading out