# Getting the value of current checkbox from a group of checkboxes with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get the value of the current checkbox from a group of checkboxes with the same class name as below. However the jquery code seems to not be acting out accordingly. Could anyone help me out with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/m8fdc/2/

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="test"/><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="test2"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="test3"/>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //set initial state.

    $('.checkbox1').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log($('.checkbox1').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You're already using `this`...so use it with `.val()`: `console.log($(this).val());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is:

```
$('.checkbox1:checked').val()
```

What you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `this` reference inside the `click` handler to get the value of the current element,

```
$('.checkbox1').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8fdc/3/)

And probably I would suggest you to use `change` event in this context rather than a `click` event. Also keep in mind that change event would get fired only when the checkbox turning into a checked state. Just decide which one would match your requirement.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8fdc/4/)

Comment: Depending on when the OP wants this to execute, `click` is probably "better": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575338/what-the-difference-between-click-and-change-on-a-checkbox . If you think about what's expected for `change` events, IE following the spec makes sense but probably isn't desired. Using `click`, the handled is executed every time the checked state is toggled

Answer (score -1):

You are reading the value of the first `.checkbox1` found if you do:

```
console.log($('.checkbox1').val());
```

When under the `click` event in jQuery you have direct access to the clicked node, so you can access it through the `this`.

You can either use the native property and do:

```
console.log(this.value);
```

or wrap it in jQuery to use jQuery's functions:

```
console.log($(this).val());
```