# Material-ui table row onClick bypass for checkbox select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the material-ui data table for sorting. This incorporates a checkbox on each row. I have made it that each row returns a click through to a link.

However, I don't want the checkbox to act as a click though and want it to behave as a checkbox and add the row to selected. But when clicking the checkbox the row link is returned.

I need to exclude that cell from the row link or someway to exclude the checkbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rlkv87vor4

This is what I have tried for the logic:

**Click handler**

```
if (event.target.classList.contains('selectCheckbox')) {
  return console.log('checkbox select');
  } else {
  return console.log('row link');
}
```

In my [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlkv87vor4) `row link` is always being returned when clicking the checkbox.

```
<TableCell padding="checkbox">
  <Checkbox className="selectCheckbox" checked={isSelected} />
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most straightforward way to deal with this is to have two separate `handleClick` methods for the checkbox and the row (e.g. `handleCheckboxClick` and `handleRowClick`).

In `handleCheckboxClick` you can then call `event.stopPropagation();` in order to prevent `handleRowClick` from being called.

So the following portions of `EnhancedTable` would change from:

```
  handleClick = (event, id) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("selectCheckbox")) {
      console.log("checkbox select");
    } else {
      console.log("row link");
    }

    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };
...
<TableRow
  hover
  onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
  role="checkbox"
  aria-checked={isSelected}
  tabIndex={-1}
  key={n.id}
  selected={isSelected}
>
  <TableCell className="selectCheckbox" padding="checkbox">
    <Checkbox
      onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
      className="selectCheckbox"
      checked={isSelected}
    />
  </TableCell>
```

to something like the following:

```
  handleCheckboxClick = (event, id) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("checkbox select");
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };
  handleRowClick = (event, id) => {
    console.log("row link");
  };
...
<TableRow
  hover
  onClick={event => this.handleRowClick(event, n.id)}
  role="checkbox"
  aria-checked={isSelected}
  tabIndex={-1}
  key={n.id}
  selected={isSelected}
>
  <TableCell className="selectCheckbox" padding="checkbox">
    <Checkbox
      onClick={event =>
        this.handleCheckboxClick(event, n.id)
      }
      className="selectCheckbox"
      checked={isSelected}
    />
```

Here's a CodeSandbox showing this approach:

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I recommend that you create your own separate question that demonstrates how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was using onChange instead of onClick. Do you know what the nuance is between them for a checkbox?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The row is responding to the click event. The row doesn't have an onChange event, so stopping propagation of the onChange event for the Checkbox will have no effect on whether the click event propagates to the row.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi As far as the difference between the events for checkboxes, this is addressed elsewhere (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575338/what-the-difference-between-click-and-change-on-a-checkbox).

Answer (score 2):

Simply add onClick on the checkbox and call `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent call onClick twice from the checkbox and from the row component !

```
handleClick = (event, id) => {
    event.stopPropagation();

    const {selected} = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    this.setState({selected: newSelected});
  };
```

```
  <TableRow
                      hover
                      onKeyDown={event => this.handleKeyDown(event, n.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                      onClick={event => onMore(event, n.id)}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >

                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox color="primary" checked={isSelected}
                                  onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}/>
                      </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are multiple issues here.

1) The className is not a valid property for the Checkbox API
https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#checkbox-api

2) `console.log(event.target)` shows that the actual click happens on an svg label used to style the input and not the input itself. So, you cannot directly use inputProps={{className:"selectedCheckbox"}} either and capture the same from the classList

You can refer this sandbox and see how you can get the desired result if you actually click the `input` : https://codesandbox.io/s/r7j4j638qn

So, a possible answer is to modify the `icon` property of the `Checkbox` component and set it to a custom icon with the specified class ? Then it should work as expected.

Comment: it still returns "row link" and not "checkbox select", so in my case it would take me to another view rather than simply checking the checkbox

Comment: okay, the title was a bit misleading, I thought you were worried about the click getting bypassed. let me look again

Comment: `className` is a valid property for any DOM element and the docs you referenced indicate "Any other properties supplied will be spread to the root element (native element)."

Comment: I could not find the className at the event target. Could be a bug? Tried the good ol' console.log() @RyanCogswell

Comment: The className is being applied to the outermost `span` that wraps the checkbox input. The overall structure created is `<span class="selectCheckbox and other classes"><span><svg/><input type="checkbox"/></span></span>`.